# rest request for search content in mayan

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, mayanedms

I have uploaded some files on the Mayan EDMS and trying to search the content of the document from the dashboard. And I am getting the files from the search result, can we get the file from the Rest Call by passing the param for search.
I found one [doc](https://docs.mayan-edms.com/chapters/rest_api.html) for rest call on the Mayan EDMS for uploading the file and getting the list of documents, but not for search Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

Mayan EDMS provides a swagger api documentation at

```
api/swagger/ui/
```

There you can search for 'search' which shows that two API searches are available:

```
​GET: api/v4//search​/advanced​/{search_model_pk}​/
GET: ​api/v4//search​/{search_model_pk}​/
```

Search_model_pk can be found here:

```
api/v4/search_models/?_fields_only=pk
```